# "Drop keyspace" command in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

i created a key space named 'hello' in Cassandra and started using it(use command). so the commands were typed after cqlsh:hello> in the cql. i then dropped the key space hello, but still it is showing cqlsh:hello> at beginning of each command. why so ?

Answer (score 3):

The keyspace is gone, but you need to reset your session context with the 'use' command.

```
cqlsh:test> create keyspace xyz with replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1} ;
cqlsh:test> use xyz;
cqlsh:xyz> drop keyspace xyz;
cqlsh:xyz> describe keyspace
Keyspace 'xyz' not found.
cqlsh:xyz>
```

Comment: in your last line it is showing cqlsh:xyz> . can't we just come out of a key space (of course not into any other key space) in that session only??

Comment: You can 'use' another keyspace, but I'm not aware that you can revert to having an unset keyspace.  What would be the purpose of unsetting the keyspace?